# Japanese equivalent of the phrase "wrapped around your finger"?

Tags: idioms, word-requests

The English phrase "wrapped around your finger" usually means that a male is so fond of a girl that she can get him to do almost anything she wants, or to give her whatever she wants.  In my case, it is my 2-year old daughter.  I could say she has me "wrapped around her finger" because she's just so cute it's hard for me to see her upset.

Does anyone have a similar phrase in Japanese?

Comment: Maybe かわいがれる?  Is かわいがらせる even a word in Japanese?

Comment: [this might be helpful](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=wrapped+around+finger&ref=sa)

Answer (score 8):

When talking about children/grandchildren and not romantic relationships, a common idiom is:

> [目に入れても痛くない{いたくない}](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AB%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E7%97%9B%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
>   (Literal: *It wouldn't hurt if I put them in my eye*)

It's similar to saying that they are the apple of your eye, and you could do anything for them.

Comment: What about when you are talking about romantic relationships?

Comment: @Blavius The link Flaw posted in the comments is pretty good. “手玉に取る” has lots of synonyms too. (None of them are restricted to romantic relationships, though.) http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%89%8B%E7%8E%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8B

Comment: I think the most literal equivalent of having someone "wrapped around one's finger" is 手玉に取っている.  But in terms of an adult's feelings toward a child, 目に入れても痛くない is a closer match in terms of context/meaning.  Thanks to @Flaw and @ mirka

Answer (score 3):

I guess a phrase similar to "dance to somebody's tune" fits here well too:

> 彼女にうまく踊らされている。